# The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger

I am getting the following error just after my host updated to Phusion Passenger 3.0. It happens "sometimes", for no apparent reason. If the problem was a gem, I guess I would always get the error.

I can reproduce the bug somewhat easily by clicking the same link over and over again.

Any idea?

---

Passenger encountered the following error:
The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Connection refused - /tmp/passenger.1.0.17525/generation-3/spawn-server/socket.8572.59234504525620

Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner::Error
Backtrace:

## File    Line    Location

0   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb   118 in `spawn_application'
1   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  257 in`spawn_rack_application'
2   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 82  in `synchronize'
3   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 79  in`synchronize'
4   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  244 in `spawn_rack_application'
5   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  137 in`spawn_application'
6   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  275 in `handle_spawn_application'
7   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    357 in`**send**'
8   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    357 in `server_main_loop'
9   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    206 in`start_synchronously'
10  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server   99

Comment: By the way, I checked production.log, and the request that crashes Passenger never gets logged.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if there is any permission issue in the /tmp directory? This message looks strange:

```
Connection refused - /tmp/passenger.1.0.17525/generation-3/spawn-server/socket.8572.59234504525620
```

Plus, last version of Passenger is 3.0.12, although an upgrade will not probably fix the issue.